# Mule ESB /bin directory path

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am using Anypoint studio for developing application on mule,I am not getting where is the /bin directory of mule.And I am using mule server3.7.3 EE,OS-centos 6.Actually I want to run mule from cmd prompt.so, I refer to "https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.3/running-mule-from-the-command-prompt".

please help me out.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no /bin directory for Anypoint Studio.

That link is talking about Mule ESB Standalone, instead of the Studio. For latest documentation please visit: [Starting and Stopping Mule ESB](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/starting-and-stopping-mule-esb). And for the Mule ESB itself you can download [Mule Enterprise Management Console](https://www.mulesoft.com/dl/mmc) or [Mule ESB Enterprise](https://www.mulesoft.com/platform/soa/mule-esb-enterprise). Then follow the instruction how to [Downloading and Starting Mule ESB](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/downloading-and-starting-mule-esb) respectively.